# Monitor image grainy after 2018-04-04 update

Tags: display-resolution, monitor

I updated my system today (April 4, 2018), immediately after which the graphics have a moire-like graininess to them. A photo of the monitor is shown below, though because it's a picture with my phone there's moire.  You can still see the grainy vertical-lines problem better here, though:

[image]

I tried changing the screen resolution and orientation to no avail. I also have only one monitor connected.

Could it be a driver issue? I'm not power user, so I don't want to fiddle with that unless I really have to.

Thank you in advance!

---

**Edit:**

Details about my graphics card are:

> 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])

```
Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 29
Memory at f7800000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
[virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: i915
Kernel modules: i915
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'grainy'?  I don't see any 'grainy' texture going on with the graphics?  (Unless you have a better screenshot than the one you provide, also ***do not*** use the site you just did to load the image, because it's got SSL problems and is a problematic site in general)

Comment: Thank you for the guidance and the edit, [@ThomasWard](https://askubuntu.com/users/10616/thomas-ward). Interesting. The image I uploaded appears grainy...on my monitor. So it is the monitor, not the images produced from it. I'm linking to an image of my screen taken from my phone [here](http://wesamuels.net/images/20180404_122829.jpg) (hopefully that site doesn't have the same security issues). Of course, that latest image _does_ have moire from my phone, but you can still see the vertical "grainy" lines especially near the top where there is less moire.

Comment: Thank you for the updated photograph with the issue.  I've edited your post accordingly (as the screenshot of the issue will not show hardware-specific issues, it'll show us what the computer thinks it's displaying, rather than the actual issue.)

Comment: Thank you again very much for your help and guidance, [@ThomasWard](https://askubuntu.com/users/10616/thomas-ward). I'm not sure how, but the issue is now fixed. Should I delete my question?